# iOS calendar repeating event

Tags: ios, calendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

Good day,
I can't add custom event in standard iOS Calendar that will be repeated (during for example 2 months).

The problem is that my event is just up to the end of current month. It doesn't matter which day it will start - it will be repeating only during this month.
Code:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
{
    if (!granted)  
        return; 
    // setting the values directly for testing purpose.
    EKRecurrenceEnd *endRecurrence = nil;
    NSMutableArray *daysOfTheWeekArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Only weekends
    [daysOfTheWeekArray addObject:[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:6]];
    [daysOfTheWeekArray addObject:[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:7]];

    endRecurrence = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7*10]]];

    //create the recurrence rule here
    EKRecurrenceRule *recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly
                                                                                interval:1
                                                                           daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheWeekArray
                                                                          daysOfTheMonth:nil
                                                                         monthsOfTheYear:nil
                                                                          weeksOfTheYear:nil
                                                                           daysOfTheYear:nil
                                                                            setPositions:nil
                                                                                     end:endRecurrence];

    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"Title";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
    [event addRecurrenceRule: recurrence];

    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
}];
```

Comment: Id didn't understood what's you're expecting and what's your code doing. It's not clear. And when you save the event, do you have error (it's not checked in your code).

Comment: @Larme I would like to create event that will be repeating for example every saturday and sunday during 3 months. This code above creates it just up to the end of current month. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try changing the parameter in `monthsOfTheYear`: an array with the 3 months (the current and the 2 next ones). You can use `NSDateComponents` on the date start (which is in your case `[NSDate date]`), to get the current one and the next 2. For today, it should be `@[@(5),@(6),@(7)]`, or as I guess (never played with it): `@[[EKRecurrenceMonthOfYear monthOfYear:5], etc]`.

Comment: @Larme, thanks, I found that it was very simple. initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly change to EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly

Answer (score 0):

Please change your frequency with `EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly`, currently it's `EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly`:

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
{
    if (!granted)  
    return;

    // setting the values directly for testing purpose.
    EKRecurrenceEnd *endRecurrence = nil;
    NSMutableArray *daysOfTheWeekArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Only weekends
    [daysOfTheWeekArray addObject:[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:6]];
    [daysOfTheWeekArray addObject:[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:7]];

    endRecurrence = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7*10]]];

    //create the recurrence rule here
    EKRecurrenceRule *recurrence = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly
                                                                            interval:1
                                                                       daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheWeekArray
                                                                      daysOfTheMonth:nil
                                                                     monthsOfTheYear:nil
                                                                      weeksOfTheYear:nil
                                                                       daysOfTheYear:nil
                                                                        setPositions:nil
                                                                                 end:endRecurrence];

    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"Title";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
    [event addRecurrenceRule: recurrence];

    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
}];
```